# How to change properties of nested elements in react-star-ratings

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, components, styles

My task is to implement styled with **classNames** (not inline/attributes) star rating using [react-star-ratings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-star-ratings). Trying to change properties of nested elements of this component (finding names of classes using DOM), but there is no solution...

1. I'm imported this component and wrapped it in a div-block (I'm using TS and this component has strange type - so I can't use classNames in attributes of this component) *If you have to say something about this issue, I will be happy...* [TSX code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hb4nj.png)
2. Found my div-block in DOM and chose nested [devtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FvWl.png)
3. Created SCSS module for change of this classes (added !important, cause component has some inline styles) [SCSS code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8c4xx.png)

So, there is no result. As u can see on DOM picture - class Rating is added, but there is no changes with nested elements...

I will be glad if somebody will help me with this issue, because I spent really lot's of time with this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've noticed, The `react-star-rating` library does not seem to support styling via the `className` attribute - in fact, it is not part of the Props for the `StarRating` component.

However, your approach of wrapping it in another container and crafting selectors to target the inner elements *should* work - to some degree
[image] - but then there seems to be no way of differentiating between filled or empty stars...

If you *must* use `react-star-rating` (there are other alternatives - or you could build your own ), a better approach, could be to use CSS custom properties:

```js
<div className="my-custom-rating">
  <StarRatings
    rating={rating}
    starRatedColor="var(--star-rated-color)"
    starEmptyColor="var(--star-empty-color)"
    changeRating={setRating}
    numberOfStars={6}
    name="rating"
  />
</div>
```

```css
.my-custom-rating {
  --star-rated-color: rebeccaPurple;
  --star-empty-color: whitesmoke;
}
```